# core data memory foot print in iOS keeps growing

Tags: ios, core-data, memory-leaks

I am trying to backup a Core Data SQLite database. This code successfully processes the running database and merges the WAL file. Unfortunately, everytime it runs I see a bump of about 3-5 MB in my memory footprint. This is causing issues after the program has run for a while. Can someone help me reclaim the memory? I thought setting everything to nil would dealloc all of the objects from RAM, but that doesn't seem to be it.

```
-(void) backupDatabaseWithThisTimeStamp: (int) timeStamp withCompletionBlock:(void (^)(void))completion {
    NSDate *backupDate = [NSDate date];
    NSError *error;

    [self.defaultPrivateQueueContext save:&error];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"error -> %@",error);
    }
    dispatch_async(self.backupQueue, ^{
        // Let's use the existing PSC
        NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *migrationPSC = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];

        // Open the store
        id sourceStore = [migrationPSC addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:[self persistentStoreURL] options:nil error:nil];

        if (!sourceStore) {
            NSLog(@" failed to add store");
            migrationPSC = nil;
        } else {
            NSLog(@" Successfully added store to migrate");

            NSError *error;
            NSLog(@" About to migrate the store...");
            id migrationSuccess = [migrationPSC migratePersistentStore:sourceStore toURL:[self backupStoreURLwithTimeStamp: timeStamp] options:[self localStoreOptions] withType:NSSQLiteStoreType error:&error];

            if (migrationSuccess) {
                NSLog(@"store successfully backed up");
                // Now reset the backup preference
                NSManagedObjectContext *tempContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
                tempContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = migrationPSC;
                tempContext.undoManager = nil;

                // clip out data
                [CDrawColorData purgeDataOlderThan:backupDate fromContext:tempContext];

                migrationPSC = nil;
                tempContext = nil;
            }
            else {
                NSLog(@"Failed to backup store: %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
                migrationPSC = nil;
            }
        }
        migrationPSC = nil;
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if (completion) {
                completion();
            }
        });
    });
}

self.backupQueue = _backupQueue = dispatch_queue_create("backup.queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);

localStoreOptions =
- (NSDictionary*)localStoreOptions {
    return @{NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption:@YES,
         NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption:@YES,
         NSSQLitePragmasOption:@{ @"journal_mode" : @"DELETE" }};
}
```

commenting out everything that happens after the migrationSuccess point does not effect the memory footprint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the issues that I've seen are directly accountable to the Xcode Scheme.
Product->Scheme
Select Run-Options
UNCHECK -> Queue Debugging (enable backtrack recording)

Once this was done, all of the memory footprint growth immediately disappeared.

Comment: Wow, I don't know how you figured this out but this seems to have solved my problem as well. Memory footprint would grow infinitely (beyond 1GB) and now lives comfortably at 25MB.

Answer (score 0):

Due to too few reps i'm writing this as an "answer" (even if it might not be *the* solution): I think it's good practice to think about "cache_size" as another NSSQLitePragmasOption and to limit it accordingly:

`NSSQLitePragmasOption:@{ @"journal_mode" : @"DELETE", @"cache_size" : @"50"}`

see [www.sqlite.org](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_cache_size) for declarations

Answer (score 0):

I think it's likely to be because all relationships in a Core Data object graph are strong references. So you're all but guaranteed retain cycles. For further diagnostics you should use Instruments' leaks tool and see what type of object appears to be leaking.

You're therefore likely to want to call `reset` on any instances you create of `NSManagedObjectContext` before discarding them. This will forcibly fault all active objects, thereby breaking any retain cycles (unless you access the objects again, naturally). It's not explicit in the documentation that a `dealloc` automatically prompts a `reset` and therefore it doesn't appear to be a contractual guarantee.